# TWRP showing error 7 even when the rom is correct

Tags: recovery-mode, custom-roms, twrp, resurrection-remix-os

Hey I was trying to flash resurrection remix 8.6.0 on my Redmi 5A(riva) but twrp showed error 7.
Then I tried flashing Pixel Experience but still error 7 i tried reflasing the recovery also tried orange fox but still nothing is working. I was able to flash rr 7.0.2. So can someone help me update it to 8.6.0.
Now whenever I boot into recovery /data is not mounting

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue but I installed Android Revolution HD and it worked! It booted and said that the /data is corrupted and it required a factory reset. I gave the only option **Reset** and it booted back to twrp(i was using it) and there it automatically formatted /data!
Hope it helps you.